# How to send data to a PHP email script with AJAX or JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm completely lost here. I want to send an email with PHP without leaving my page. But I can't figure out how to get the data to the PHP file to email it.  And when I do get it there, I would be lost.  So any help with what the PHP file should look like would be great too.
Here is the form.

```
<table id="dialog">
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" size="20" class="tbow" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" size="20" class="tbow" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Your Phone Number" size="20" class="tbow" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="25" class="tbow" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="button" value="Send!" onclick="senem();" id="sender" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

And I've tried this...

```
function senem(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mmaa.php",
            data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&number=" + number = "&message=" + message,
            success: alert("It works!!!");
        });
 }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: function senem(){
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mmaa.php",
                data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&number=" + number = "&message=" + message,
                success: alert("It works!!!");
            });
        }

Comment: Please update your question with this code for readability :-)

Comment: Thank you for helping me clear up my question.

Comment: working solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029703/jquery-using-ajax-to-send-data-and-save-in-php/19029778#19029778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not intended as a copy-and-paste job, but should give you the building blocks to write it yourself:

Your javascript function;

```
function senem() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://location/of/script.php",
        data: { var1: "foo", var2: "bar" },
    });
}
```

and in the php;

```
<?php
    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['var2']; //do something interesting with these

    $to = "john@example.com";
    $subject = "Wooo Email!";
    $message = "Sorry John, you're fired.";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: system@yourdomain.com\r\n");
?>
```

The values of var1 and var2 you will probably want to assign clientside, using jQuery (eg $("#name").val(); ) and you will also need to install and configure an SMTP server alongside Apache (use Exim, and find a friendly geek to help you).

PS: the \r\n is because SMTP shares some syntax with HTTP, it's not important, but the mail command probably won't work without them.

Comment: @TannerEllis, if it works, you should probably accept the answer so that other users can find it easily :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm new at this. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

I will remove the onlick event from button and do it an [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way

```
<input type="button" value="Send!" id="sender" />
```

Script

```
$(function(){

 $("#sender").click(function(){
    $.post("yourserver.php", 
                          { name: $("#name").val(),
                            email:$("#email").val(),
                            number : $("#number").val(), 
                            message=$("#message").val()
                          },
                         function(result){
                            //Show the result from server page to the user. 
                            alert(result)
                         });    
  });
});
```

Have your php page accepts this values and then do send the email after proper validation. You may respond some message back ( "Ex : Email sent") and that will be available in the `result` variable.

Make sure you have jQuery library loaded to your page.

Read this pages for better understanding of how jQuery post works http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa : Seperate behaviour from markup. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Eeeek what idiot came up with that term for functionality and presentation separation ;-)