# How change PHP Email form (return section) to match with Javascript and html template?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

Recently I posted a question [PHP Script not send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283902/php-contact-form-used-in-html-5-template-but-not-email-sends) and read lots of similar topics on SO like as [AJAX JQUERY HTML EMAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264356/how-to-send-data-to-a-php-email-script-with-ajax-or-json) topics but none of them solved my problem.

My problem is that when email is successfully sent (I check it), part of **HTML** is not run and whole page being refreshed not as main template: (I think I couldn't send response for **PHP** when send back to **HTML**). my goal is just change PHP file to works.

In the main template, the result of emails (sent or failed) is done perfect as follows, but in my version there is a problem to show like as this:

[image]

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="alert alert-success hidden animated fadeIn" id="contactSuccess">
   <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent to us.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger hidden animated shake" id="contactError">
   <strong>Error!</strong> There was an error sending your message.
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    "use strict";
    e("#contact-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(s) {
            var o = e(s),
                a = e("#contactSuccess"),
                t = e("#contactError"),
                r = e(this.submitButton);
            r.button("loading"), e.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: o.attr("action"),
                data: {
                    name: o.find("#name").val(),
                    email: o.find("#email").val(),
                    subject: o.find("#subject").val(),
                    message: o.find("#message").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function(s) {
                    return "object" == typeof s.responseJSON && "success" == s.responseJSON.response ? (a.removeClass("hidden"), t.addClass("hidden"), o.find(".controled").val("").blur().parent().removeClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error").find("label.error").remove(), o.find(".controled").removeClass("error"), a.offset().top - 80 < e(window).scrollTop() && e("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: a.offset().top - 80
                    }, 300), r.button("reset"), void e(".controled").keyup(function() {
                        a.addClass("hidden")
                    })) : (t.removeClass("hidden"), a.addClass("hidden"), o.find(".controled").val("").blur().parent().removeClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error").find("label.error").remove(), t.offset().top - 80 < e(window).scrollTop() && e("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: t.offset().top - 80
                    }, 300), o.find(".has-success").removeClass("has-success"), r.button("reset"), void e(".controled").keyup(function() {
                        t.addClass("hidden")
                    }))
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

#### PHP:

```php
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        window.location = 'contact_page.html#contactSuccess';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        window.location = 'contact_page.html#contactError';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Seeing that the JS part contains `complete: `, this presumably is the success handler for some AJAX request? And you expect some `responseJSON` property to exist on the response? If so - why? Your PHP code that you have shown (and that I’m assuming is what responds to the AJAX request) doesn’t respond with JSON - it outputs HTML code, a `script` element to be precise.

Comment: @04FS I'm a novice in this fields. I want to create my own site with one templates that PHP-contact-form is absent in this template. how I can solve the problem? would you please more clearly for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you just output the url in php side and then in the javascript side you call the script that you want:

**PHP Side**

```
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
if ($mail_status) {
    echo "{'url':'contact_page.html#contactSuccess'}";
} else {
    echo "{'url':'contact_page.html#contactError'}";
}
```

**Javascript Side**

```
complete: function(){
   ...
   window.location = s.responseJSON.url
   ...
}
```

Comment: @James I test it. echo works and display on screen, I think I should return success because we see in JS return "object" == typeof s.responseJSON && "success" ? am I right? my problem not solved !

Comment: @James I correct and I think now correct I test via this code:

if ($mail_status) { 
    
 echo "{'url':'index.html#contactSuccess'}";
}
else { 
    echo "{'url':'index.html#contactError'}";

}'

Comment: @James infact I dont want change JS I want to change just PHP to match with this JS. this is my goals.

Comment: @James would you please help me? really I sad.

Comment: if you change only the php method, try to use this: < ?php header("Location: {URL}"); ?> where the {{URL}} is the contact_page.***. Please be sure don't make any output before call this method.